# What concerns this php code sequence?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use a wordpress theme

This is the demo

http://venusdemo.com/wpopal/mix/fashion/

At the top there is a menu "account" and contains submenus

How is created the sub menu? Admin panel there is something to refer to submenus

I found this php code

```
 <div class="acount quick-button">
                        <div class="button heading">
                            <span class="title"><?php echo __('Account', TEXTDOMAIN); ?> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"> </i></span>
                        </div>
                        <?php if(has_nav_menu( 'topmenu' )){ ?>
                                <?php
                                    $args = array(
                                        'theme_location'  => 'topmenu',
                                        'container_class' => '',
                                        'menu_class'      => 'menu-topbar'
                                    );
                                    wp_nav_menu($args);
                                ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
```

Can I create these submenus administration panel? Or must manually create HTML / CSS

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those areas are first registered (created) through a PHP function (your `functions.php` file or similar in your theme directory.

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'topmenu', 'Top Menu' );
}
```

Then called into the menu like this:

```
 <?php if(has_nav_menu( 'topmenu' )){ ?>
       <?php
          $args = array(
          'theme_location'  => 'topmenu',
          'container_class' => '',
          'menu_class'      => 'menu-topbar'
            );
          wp_nav_menu($args);
       ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Any additional would follow the same procedure, just change the register values (the first is the name referenced in the theme_location and the second is used in your Administration > Menus area.)

To create the drop-down items, you go to the menu in Administration > Menus, select the menu to edit from the dropdown, and then click items to add and drag under another item to make it a dropdown item (child of the parent).

Comment: I just did. That's my answer. You're not going to get any more specific than that.